# Cannot read property of listen of undefined Vue-Router-next

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-v4-reproduction-l5fzm?file=/index.html

Getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'listen' of undefined 
>   at createRouter (vue-router.esm-bundler.js:2269)
>   at main.js:16
>   createRouter @ vue-router.esm-bundler.js:2269
>   (anonymous) @ main.js:16

#### Code Sample: How to reproduce

```js
const { createRouter, createWebHistory, createWebHashHistory } = VueRouter
const { createApp } = Vue

const Home = {
  template: `<div>home</div>`,
}

const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

const router = createRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
    { path: '/bar', component: Bar },
  ],
})

const app = createApp({})
app.use(router)

window.vm = app.mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the history key is a required parameter and is resolved in the [vue-router-next](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/blob/master/README.md) docs.

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
// there is also createWebHashHistory and createMemoryHistory

createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [],
})
```

Comment: I get createWebHistory is not a function and when I print it is is undefined. What could be the problem

Comment: sorry @Abhi but you should include a codesandbox, i'm unable to reproduce with the following codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-v4-reproduction-l5fzm?file=/index.html

Comment: Nvm. It was because createWebHistory is available from Vue router v4 and I was using 3.3.7